# Broadcast receiver responding just for one day

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I want to get the notification of namaz time everyday. Suppose 5 wakth namaj notification. So I make a app and used broadcast receiver for working in background and send me notification when the exact time hit. My app works fine for single day. After passing one day, it does not send me notification anymore. I am attaching my code here

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c4 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c5 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c6 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.set(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR), c1.get(Calendar.MONTH), c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 4, 5, 0);
    c2.set(c2.get(Calendar.YEAR), c2.get(Calendar.MONTH), c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 5, 30, 0);
    c3.set(c3.get(Calendar.YEAR), c3.get(Calendar.MONTH), c3.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 12, 21, 0);
    c4.set(c4.get(Calendar.YEAR), c4.get(Calendar.MONTH), c4.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 16, 10, 0);
    c5.set(c5.get(Calendar.YEAR), c5.get(Calendar.MONTH), c5.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 17, 30, 0);
    c6.set(c6.get(Calendar.YEAR), c6.get(Calendar.MONTH), c6.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 19, 10, 0);
    setAlarm(c1.getTimeInMillis(), "Tahajjud");
    setAlarm(c2.getTimeInMillis(), "Fojor");
    setAlarm(c3.getTimeInMillis(), "Juhur");
    setAlarm(c4.getTimeInMillis(), "Asor");
    setAlarm(c5.getTimeInMillis(), "Magrib");
    setAlarm(c6.getTimeInMillis(), "Esha");
```

And my setAlarm method is

```
    String namajText = namaj;
    AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(BackgroundNotificationOnTime.this,MyAlarm2.class);

    intent.putExtra("Namaj", namajText);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,count,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeInMillis,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

    count++;
```

That's my onReceive method

```
String namajText = intent.getStringExtra("Namaj");
    int nId = 0;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Namaj Alert")
            .setContentText(namajText+" namaj wakth started.")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);

    Uri path = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(path);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(nId,builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` for your `PendingIntent`, that's why each alarm fires only once. So you need to use another value for repeating alarms, e.g. 0.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_ONE_SHOT) for `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`:

> Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int, Intent, int).
>
> If set, after send() is called on it, it will be automatically canceled for you and any future attempt to send through it will fail.

Comment: then which one i should i use instead of FLAG_ONE_SHOT